# AWS EC2MetadataUtils do not work from ColdFusion

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, coldfusion

This question is related to this:  [AWS SecretsManager works in Eclipse, can't connect to Service Endpoint in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474271/aws-secretsmanager-works-in-eclipse-cant-connect-to-service-endpoint-in-coldfu)

I have the following function written in Java using the AWS SDK v1.12.459:  (Courtesy of [How to get accesskey, secretkey using java aws SDK running on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287920/how-to-get-accesskey-secretkey-using-java-aws-sdk-running-on-ec2))

```
public String getEC2InstanceKeys() {
    String result = "";

    try
    {
        Map<String,EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential> credMap = EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMSecurityCredentials();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential>> it = credMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential> pair = (Map.Entry<String,EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential>)it.next();

            EC2MetadataUtils.IAMSecurityCredential cred = pair.getValue();
                
            result = cred.accessKeyId + "|" + cred.secretAccessKey;
        }             
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         result = e.getMessage();
    }
      
    return result;    
}
```

I am running this via RDP into an Amazon EC2.

When I run this in Eclipse or from the Command Line via the main function, it works every time.

When I run this function from ColdFusion running from the EC2, it gives me an empty string.  No error, just an empty string.

```
<cfscript>
    obj = CreateObject("java","SMtest");
    obj.init();
    y = obj.getEC2InstanceKeys();
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#obj#" >
<cfoutput>#y#</cfoutput>
```

What is preventing me from getting the correct in ColdFusion ?

Comment: My first thought is:  "Does the server have access to the class/jar file that is "SMTest"?  Also, you didn't include the error?

Comment: I have added a simple dummy function that just outputs "HELLO" to confirm access to the class, and as stated above, there was no error.